# Setting the values in POJO Class after fetching the values from db via hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm

I am working on a hibernate app wherein in the DAO I run the following query

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Collection<Owner> findOwners(String lastName) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Owner owner where owner.lastName like :lastName")
                .setString("lastName", lastName + "%").list();
    }
```

Fetch the owners from the db and display in the jsp.

My POJO class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OWNERS")
public class Owner extends Person implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="owner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Pet> pets;


    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return this.telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    protected void setPetsInternal(Set<Pet> pets) {
        this.pets = pets;
    }

    protected Set<Pet> getPetsInternal() {

    //A null should not be returned; if returned will throw a NullPointerException
        if (this.pets == null) {
            this.pets = new HashSet<Pet>();
        }
        return this.pets;
    }



    public List<Pet> getPets() {
        List<Pet> sortedPets = new ArrayList<Pet>(getPetsInternal());


        PropertyComparator.sort(sortedPets, new MutableSortDefinition("name", true, true));
        //returns an immutable list of sortedPets
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedPets);
    }

    /*public void addPet(Pet pet) {
        getPetsInternal().add(pet);
        pet.setOwner(this);
    }
*/
    /**
     * Return the Pet with the given name, or null if none found for this Owner.
     *
     * @param name to test
     * @return true if pet name is already in use
     */
    public Pet getPet(String name) {
        return getPet(name, false);
    }

    /**
     * Return the Pet with the given name, or null if none found for this Owner.
     *
     * @param name to test
     * @return true if pet name is already in use
     */
    public Pet getPet(String name, boolean ignoreNew) {
        name = name.toLowerCase();
        for (Pet pet : getPetsInternal()) {
            if (!ignoreNew || !pet.isNew()) {
                String compName = pet.getName();
                compName = compName.toLowerCase();
                if (compName.equals(name)) {
                    return pet;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringCreator(this)

        .append("id", this.getId())

        .append("new", this.isNew())

        .append("lastName", this.getLastName())

        .append("firstName", this.getFirstName())

        .append("address", this.address)

        .append("city", this.city)

        .append("telephone", this.telephone)

        .toString();
    }
}
```

My question may seem a little bizzare, I know in the jsp the get*() methods are being called by the EL, but where are the set*() methods for the Owner class called? How is the value being set in the POJO?

Are the values after being fetched from the db being set in the POJO internally by hibernate?

Comment: Actually, Owner isn't POJO. It's DS class, due to @Entity adnotation. Also, we shouldn't put logic into ds classes. It should be in Dao/Bo class.

Comment: What is a DS class can you plz elaborate?

Comment: Ds is a class which is mapped to database entity. It should contain only fields and getters & setters.